# サンプルコードを組み合わせたところ、リンク（内部、外部）できない

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

ハンバーガーメニューとスライダーのサンプルコードを組み合わせたところ、ハンバーガーメニューについては問題なく開き、外部へのリンクもできますが、外部への画像リンクや、フッターからトップページへの内部リンクができません。

menu css から以下の部分を削除し、フッターにカーソルを当てると人差し指マークには変わりますが、リンクはしませんでした。

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

**現状のソースコード**

```js
var mqWidth = 680,
    scrollTrigger = 40,
    isMobile = null,
    burgerCheckbox = $('#humberger_check'), 
    hiddenMenu = $('.hidden_menu li'),
    slideBar = $('.menu_underline'),
    headerBar = $('.header_bar');

function sliderBarAnimation(){
  if ( $(window).width() > mqWidth ){
    if (isMobile === false) return;
    isMobile = false;
    hiddenMenu.off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(
      // nmouseenter
      function(){
        var current = $(this),
            barColor = current.data('bar-color');
        slideBar.addClass('visible').css({
          'top':'auto',
          'left' : current.position().left,
          'background-color':barColor
        })
      },
      //mouseleave
      function(){
        slideBar.removeClass('visible');
      }
    );
  } else {
    if (isMobile === true) return;
    isMobile = true;
    hiddenMenu.off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(
      // nmouseenter
      function(){
        var current = $(this),
            barColor = current.data('bar-color');
        slideBar.addClass('visible').css({
          'left':0,
          'top':current.offset().top + 60,
          'background-color':barColor
        });
      },
      //mouseleave
      function(){
        slideBar.css({'top':0}).removeClass('visible');
      }
    );
  }
}
$(window).on({
  'resize' : function(){
      sliderBarAnimation();
    },
  'scroll' : function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollTrigger){
      headerBar.addClass('show-bg');
    } else {
      headerBar.removeClass('show-bg');
    }
  }
});
(function(){
  sliderBarAnimation();
  
  hiddenMenu.on('click', function(){
    var current = $(this);
    current.addClass('selected');
    setTimeout(function(){
      current.removeClass('selected');
      burgerCheckbox.prop('checked',false);
    }, 400);
  });
  hiddenMenu.children('a:not([target]):not([href^="tel:"])').on('click', function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    if (!url) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
      window.location = url;
    },400);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
（menu css）

@charset "utf-8";
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Lato, Arial, "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro W3", Meiryo, sans-serif;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body a, body a:visited {
  color: #efefef;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5% 40px;
}

.hidden_menu, .hidden_menu ul {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hidden_menu ul li, .menu_underline, .header_bar::before {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.humberger, .hidden_menu, .hidden_menu ul, .header_bar, .container {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hidden_menu ul li::before, .header_bar::before, .container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#humberger_check {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#humberger_check:checked + .humberger {
  transform: translateY(160px);
}
#humberger_check:checked + .humberger span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#humberger_check:checked + .humberger span::before {
  top: 2px;
  transition: top 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333) 0.15s, transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0.22s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
#humberger_check:checked + .humberger span::after {
  top: 6px;
  transition: top 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333), transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0.22s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 6px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 6px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
#humberger_check:checked ~ .header_bar,
#humberger_check:checked ~ .container {
  transform: translateY(160px);
}
#humberger_check:checked ~ .hidden_menu {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
#humberger_check:checked ~ .hidden_menu ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotateX(0);
}

.humberger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5vw;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}
.humberger span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto auto -15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color .1s linear .13s;
}
.humberger span::before, .humberger span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.humberger span::before {
  top: 12px;
  transition: top 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}
.humberger span::after {
  top: 24px;
  transition: top 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hidden_menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1600px;
  perspective: 1600px;
  background-color: #222;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.hidden_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.hidden_menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.hidden_menu ul li::before {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(1)::before {
  background-color: #FA3687;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(2)::before {
  background-color: #21D7A8;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(3)::before {
  background-color: #1E9ED4;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(4)::before {
  background-color: #B0D44A;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(5)::before {
  background-color: #A865D5;
}
.hidden_menu ul li.selected::before {
  animation: scaling .4s linear;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
.hidden_menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hidden_menu ul li i {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.menu_underline {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu_underline.visible {
  height: 3px;
}

.header_bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 5vw;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    z-index: 2;
}
.header_bar::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  opacity: 0;
}
.header_bar.show-bg::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.header_bar h1 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 26px 0 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
    transform: skew(-10deg);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-image:;
}
.container::before {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 4vw;
  padding: 0 5vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.content h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
  font-size: 38px;
}

@keyframes scaling {
  50% {
    opacity: .28;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 680px) {
  #humberger_check:checked + .humberger,
  #humberger_check:checked ~ .header_bar,
  #humberger_check:checked ~ .container {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }

  .hidden_menu {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .hidden_menu ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .hidden_menu ul li i {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  .menu_underline {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
}

（slider css）

@charset "utf-8";

[class^="swiper-button-"], .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet, .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet::before {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

[class^="swiper-slide-shadow-"] {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #888;
    clear: both;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34vw;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .6s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .6s ease, transform .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .6s ease, transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
}
.swiper-container:hover .swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-container:hover .swiper-button-next {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.swiper-container.loading {
  opacity: 0;
}
.swiper-container.scale-out {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
          transform: scale(0.7);
}
.swiper-container.scale-in {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-perspective: 1600px;
          perspective: 1600px;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active {
  z-index: 2;
}
.swiper-slide .entity-img {
  display: none;
}
.swiper-slide .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px) translateX(100px);
          transform: translateZ(100px) translateX(100px);
}
.swiper-slide .content .title {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.swiper-slide .content .caption {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

[class^="swiper-button-"] {
  width: 44px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
          transform: translateX(50px);
}

.swiper-button-next {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
          transform: translateX(-50px);
}

.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 9px;
  position: relative;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: .4;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet:hover, .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active::before {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MENU</title>
<link href="css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/container.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type=<"css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" role="button" title="menu" id="humberger_check" />
<label for="humberger_check" class="humberger" aria-hidden="true" title="menu">
  <span></span>
</label>
<header class="header_bar">
  <h1>SITE TITLE</h1>
</header>
<main class="container">
  <section class="content">
    <h2>3D Rotating Hidden Menu</h2>
  </section>
</main>
<nav class="hidden_menu">
  <ul>
    <li data-bar-color="#FA3687">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-picture"></i>IMAGE</a>
    </li>
    <li data-bar-color="#21D7A8">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-film"></i>VIDEO</a>
    </li>
    <li data-bar-color="#1E9ED4">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-music"></i>MUSIC</a>
    </li>
    <li data-bar-color="#B0D44A">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-headphones"></i>PERSONAL</a>
    </li>
    <li data-bar-color="#A865D5">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-cogs"></i>SETTINGS</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="menu_underline"></span>
</nav>

<section class="swiper-container loading">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-test-set="test" style="background-image:url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLbVhsNzdIYmlfN1E)">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLbVhsNzdIYmlfN1E" class="entity-img" />
      <div class="content">
        <p class="title">Shaun Matthews</p>
        <span class="caption">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLWTdaX3J5b1VueDg)">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLWTdaX3J5b1VueDg" class="entity-img" />
      <div class="content">
        <p class="title">Alexis Berry</p>
        <span class="caption">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLRml1b3B6eXVqQ2s)">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLRml1b3B6eXVqQ2s" class="entity-img" />
      <div class="content">
        <p class="title">Billie Pierce</p>
        <span class="caption">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLVUpEems2ZXpHYVk)">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLVUpEems2ZXpHYVk" class="entity-img" />
      <div class="content">
        <p class="title">Trevor Copeland</p>
        <span class="caption">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLNXBIcEdOUFVIWmM)">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLNXBIcEdOUFVIWmM" class="entity-img" />
      <div class="content">
        <p class="title">Bernadette Newman</p>
        <span class="caption">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
</section>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="slide">
    <div id="slide-in">
        <p id="page-top"><a href="#wrap">PAGE TOP</a></p>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 「フッターからトップページへの内部リンクができません」と書かれているのは、HTMLの
            <p id="page-top"><a href="#wrap">PAGE TOP</a></p>

の部分の事かと思われますが、
　HTMLの中には、　"#wrap"というアンカーが存在しません。無いものにリンクできないのは、当然だと思います。

Comment: Fumu 7様　有難うございます。<body>下に<div id="wrap">を追記いたしましたところ、他のページで試してtopに行きましたが、ハンバーガーメニューのコードが入るとこの組み合わせではだめでした。

Comment: スニペッドで実行しようと思いましたが、エラーがでて実行できませんでした。ソースコードを張り付ける場合は再現性が取れる、このサイトだけで完結できるコードを記述してもらえると回答者側も回答がしやすいです。

Comment: keitaro_so様　有難うございます。初心者であり、完結できるコードを記述したいのですが、文字数に制限があり、全て貼り付けできませんでした。

Comment: 因みにこのサンプルのurlが https://digipress.info/tech/3d-rotating-hidden-menu-sample/とhttps://digipress.info/tech/introducing-swiper-js/
の3D キューブ回転スライダーになります。 宜しくお願いします。

Comment: すべてを張り付ける必要はないです。必要な箇所だけ抜き出して再現性の取れる最低限のコードを記述してもらえるとよいでしょう。 [参考ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: keitaro_so様　有難うございます。menu.cssのcontent部分を削除致しましたところ、無事リンクができるようになりました。

Comment: 解決したのであれば自己回答としてほかの困っている人たちにも共有できるように回答として投稿しましょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

menu.cssのcontent部分を削除致しましたところ、無事リンクができるようになりました。